# Sending multiple attachments using Google Appscript and Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a program I use to send mails using data in Google Sheet and typing the file name in the column in Sheet.
This was working fine as long as I had to send only one attachment.

However, now that I'm trying to send 2 attachments, I am not sure what change I need to make.
I looked at other responses - where you specify two variables instead of one - however in my case, its not definitive whether I'll mail 1 or 2 or 3 attachments, so I require a solution which can work with n number of files.

Attaching my current code for reference:

```
var attach = ws.getRange(lr, 17).getValue();
var file1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName(attach).next();
GmailApp.sendEmail('',
"" + sub + "",
'',
{htmlBody: htmlforemail,
bcc: emails.join(","),
attachments: file1
}
```

Comment: Consider providing the code related to how you are getting the file names that will be sent as attachments. If you have names instead of IDs, I assume that you don't have multiple files with the same name, which could bring some ambiguity to the table?

Comment: So I am getting the code as follows -
var attach = ws.getRange(lr, 17).getValue(); //this takes the file name
var file2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName(attach).next(); 
Apologies I think I posted it incorrectly in the question - Im editing it now as well

Comment: I thought you wanted to retrieve several file names?

Comment: @Iamblichus no not retrieve; I will be mentioning several file names - which I then want to send as attachment. The file name is mentioned in the attach variable, now question is if there are more than 1 file names, how do I retrieve those.

Comment: Oh you mean there are several file names on the same cell? Are they comma-separated?

Comment: Yes buddy correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue and solution:

If I understand your situation correctly, you want to send multiple Drive files as attachments in an email. The names of these files can be found in a single cell in your spreadsheet, in a comma-separated string.

In this case, as you can see in the documentation, the [attachments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) parameter requires an array of [BlobSource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source.html) to be provided, with each element in this array corresponding to each file.

Therefore, you should do the following:

- Split the comma-separated string into an array with the file names (see [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)).
- For each file name, look for the file in Drive (using `getFilesByName` and `next`, as you are already doing). You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the file names array to a files array.
- Provide the resulting array as `attachments`.

#### Code snippet:

```
var attach = ws.getRange(lr, 17).getValue().split(",");
var files = attach.map(fileName => DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next());
GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, '', {
  htmlBody: htmlforemail,
  bcc: emails.join(","),
  attachments: files
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you [look at the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) you will see that the `attachments` parameter expects to receive an array of files. So just push the files you need there and that's it.

Comment: attachments does accept array, however I will need to create multiple variables. But I am not sure about the number of attachements I will have - so the code will give an error that the file is not found.

Comment: why do you need multiple variables? you just need an array

Comment: please share how you plan to decide how many attachments to use

Comment: create and array and push the values into the array.

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk how can I create an array of files in the driveapp property, can you help?
Basically - I enter the file names in the cell like this - FileA.pdf, FileB.pdf

Now how do I feed these into the Driveapp Property in order for it to work?

Comment: If the file names are in a google sheet, you read their values, get the blob and push them into your array, just like you would do with any value. I'm not sure I fully understand your issue though